# Can't fetch perticular details from a json response in my react app

Tags: json, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I use a third party service to get some response of request. The response I get is a json array but I'm unable to get the particular details of it.

```
const dispatchListColumns = [
    {
        dataField: 'id',
        text: 'id',
        sort: true,
        formatter: (cell, row) => {
            return (row)

        }
    },
    {
        dataField: 'tel',
        text: 'Telephone Number',
        sort: true,
        formatter: (cell, row) => {
            return (row)

        }
    },



];
```

this is my columns of the table, when I return 'row' it gives me response as:

```
["[{"_id":"5d709d18e148b95aeccde88d","tel":"95604535…,"tripId":"5d6e3631a07e4e6f69199490","address":"S", "hop No.66, Main Road shalimar, Block BH, Sahipur V… 110088, India","distance_remained":363605,"time_", "remained":22003,"curr_ETA":"2019-09-08T08:17:07.43…":"2019-09-05T05:28:56.424Z"},{"_id":"5d7072d1e14", "8b95aeccdc004","tel":"9560453585","loc":[28.713564…a07e4e6f69199490","address":"BG/9, Rajender Singh", " Sehrawat Marg, Block BG, Shalimar Bagh, Delhi, 11…ed":364080,"time_remained":22056,"curr_ETA":"2019", "-09-08T05:22:36.683Z","city":"Delhi","createdAt":"…_id":"5d70488ae148b95aeccd9595","tel":"9560453585", "","loc":[28.713564,77.16004],"tripId":"5d6e3631a07…9, Rajender Singh Sehrawat Marg, Block BG, Shalim", "ar Bagh, Delhi, 110088, India","distance_remained"…,"curr_ETA":"2019-09-08T02:32:59.230Z","city":"De", "lhi","createdAt":"2019-09-04T23:28:10.632Z"},{"_id…"tel":"9560453585","loc":[28.713478,77.16007],"tr", "ipId":"5d6e3631a07e4e6f69199490","address":"BG/16,…hi, 110088, India","distance_remained":364961,"ti", "me_remained":22078,"curr_ETA":"2019-09-07T23:32:43…dAt":"2019-09-04T20:27:47.986Z"},{"_id":"5d6ff3fd", "e148b95aeccd3caf","tel":"9560453585","loc":[28.718…631a07e4e6f69199490","address":"Chaudhary Meher C", "hand Yadav Marg, Block BC, Beri Wala Bagh, Shalima…,"distance_remained":364919,"time_remained":22036", ","curr_ETA":"2019-09-07T20:31:49.684Z","city":"Del…7:27:25.507Z"},{"_id":"5d6fc9c6e148b95aeccd1200",", ""tel":"9560453585","locand ":[28.720737,77.16147],"tri…0","address":"195, Shalimar Bagh Azapur Mandi Rai", "lway Under Bridge, Mutiny Memorial, Azadpur, Delhi…mained":363410,"time_remained":21746,"curr_ETA":"", "2019-09-07T17:13:04.801Z","city":"Delhi","createdA…}]
```

And this is how I pass my data into it:

```
         <CardHeader>
         <b>Loading Plan</b>
         </CardHeader>
         <div>
         <DataTable columns={dispatchListColumns} data={plan}/>
         </div>
         </Card>
```

And this is my API call:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [plan, setPlan] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getTrucks = async () => {
            refreshing();
            const truckData = await assignedTrucks();
            setData(truckData);
            console.log(truckData, "truck")
        };
        const getLoacation = async () => {
            const locationPlan = await trackNow();
            setPlan(locationPlan);
            console.log(locationPlan, "locationPlan");
        };

        getTrucks();
        getLoacation();
    },[assignedTrucks],[trackNow]

    );
```

Now lets say I want to get details of ID and address from this data, for that I have tried `row._id` and `row.address` but in console I get Undefined, I'm stuck here now with all these details.

Comment: Could you share what this `console.log(truckData, "truck")` prints in the console ?

Comment: the Truck data gives the details of truck that I want to track and the problem I'm facing is with trackNow, yet the console.log of truck data is here:
```(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 7, truck_name: "10 TYRE 14 Ton", comments: "", origin: "Dehradun", destination: "Gurgaon", …}
1: {id: 6, truck_name: "10 TYRE 15 Ton", comments: "", origin: "Delhi", destination: "Mumbai", …}```
but getLocation is what I'm concerned with right now @Raja